# select top 2 bestseller products from each brands

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, mysql-5.7

A simple query like this:

```
SELECT
    products.*,
    SUM(orderdetails.quantity) AS sold
FROM products
RIGHT JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id, products.brand_id
ORDER BY sold DESC
```

How to change it to get only two products of each brands?

Comment: Two random products of each brand, or can you be more specific?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it's `ORDER BY sold DESC`, means two top products

Comment: is products.id unique ?

Comment: which MySQL Version you are using ?

Comment: @guigoz Yes, it is

Comment: @BerndBuffen Mysql 5.7

Comment: I would have been tempted to wait a few hours before accepting an answer, but there we go. Maybe next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
 SELECT ranked.*
   FROM
     (SELECT products.*, 
             @product_rank := IF(@current_brand = products.brand_id, @product_rank + 1, 1) AS product_rank,
             @current_brand := products.brand_id 
       FROM ( SELECT
              products.*,
              SUM(orderdetails.quantity) AS sold
              FROM products
              JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.product_id = products.id
              GROUP BY products.id, products.brand_id
              ORDER BY products.brand_id,sold  DESC
             ) products      
     ) ranked
   WHERE product_rank <= 2
```

[SqlFiddle Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dcd7/1)